# Vectorfields satisfying SO(3) algebra 2 dimensional?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth connected manifold and $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$ vectorfields whose commutators satisfy the $SO(3)$ algebra:
\begin{equation}
[V_1,V_2]=V_3
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
[V_2,V_3]=V_1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
[V_3,V_1]=V_2
\end{equation}
Is the vectorspace $V_x = \langle V_1(x),V_2(x),V_3(x)\rangle \subset T_x M$ at most two-dimensional $\forall x \in M$? If so, is any compact submanifold $N \subset M$ that is an integral manifold of $\langle V_1,V_2,V_3 \rangle$ homeomorphic to a sphere?

See e.g. https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll7.html to appreciate the relevance of this question.

EDIT: The answer from Andrew can in fact also be used to negatively answer the same question as before but now with $(M,g)$ a three dimensional (semi)-Riemannian manifold of our choice where $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$ are required to be Killing vectorfields. We can endow $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the metric $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2+dv^2$ for which the vectorfields $V_i$ indeed generate isometries (Killing vectorfields). The three vectorfields are also tangent to $S^3\subset \mathbb{R}^4$. Hence, taking $(M,g)=(S^3,\gamma)$ where $\gamma$ is the induced metric and where we take the induced vectorfields $W_1=V_1\left.\right|_{S^3},W_2=V_2\left.\right|_{S^3},W_3=V_3\left.\right|_{S^3}$. $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ are Killing vectorfields on $(M,g)$ which span the full 3-dimensional tangent space of $M$ at every point $x$. This follows from
\begin{equation}
\det((r\partial_r,V_1,V_2,V_3)^t)=\det\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z & v \\ -y & x & v & -z \\ -z & -v & x & y \\ -v & z & -y & x\end{pmatrix}=(x^2+y^2+z^2+v^2)^2.
\end{equation}

Comment: I'm not sure your edit is correct... you only used $[V_1, V_2] = V_3$, so if that argument works then it actually proves that the Lie bracket of any two vector fields is in their span... which makes the assumption of the Frobenius theorem look awful superfluous, no? I think the issue is that your formulation is only true if you interpret the assumption as $V_i(f) = 0$ at a single point, while you're using it in a neighbourhood.

Comment: You're right. My argument was circular. I implicitly assumed the existence of a function $f$ such that $V_1(f)=0$ and $V_2(f)=0$ in a neighborhood, which means that that $f=C$ are integral manifolds of $V_1$ and $V_2$ which in turn requires $V_3=[V_1,V_2] \in <V_1,V_2>$. Edit deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Lie}[1]{#1}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\mathbf{e}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$The Lie algebra $\Lie{su}(2)$ is isomorphic to the Lie algebra $\Lie{so}(3)$ because $SU(2)$ double-covers $SO(3)$. The left action of $SU(2)$ on $\Cpx^{2} \simeq \Reals^{4}$ has three-dimensional orbits, which (assuming I understand your question) shows that $V_{x}$ can be three-dimensional.

A concrete example of three linear independent vectorfields obtained in this way is
\begin{equation}
V_1:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4:(x,y,z,v)\mapsto\frac{1}{2}(-y,x,v,-z)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V_2:(x,y,z,v)\mapsto\frac{1}{2}(-z,-v,x,y)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V_3:(x,y,z,v)\mapsto\frac{1}{2}(-v,z,-y,x).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Even when $n=3$, the system
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
& [V_1,V_2]=V_3 \\
& [V_2,V_3]=V_1 \\
& [V_3,V_1]=V_2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is way too undetermined to have $\dim \langle V_1(x),V_2(x),V_3(x)\rangle <3$ everywhere. Take for instance the manifold $M=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus L$, where $L$ is the vertical line determined by $x^2+y^2=0$, and the following three vectorfields (which are globally defined):
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
& V_1(x,y,z)=-y\partial_x+x\partial_y = \partial_{\varphi} \\
& V_2(x,y,z)=(-z\partial_y+y\partial_z)+\lambda \frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}(x\partial_x+y\partial_y+z\partial_z) = (-z\partial_y+y\partial_z) + \lambda \sin(\varphi)r\partial_r\\
& V_3(x,y,z)=(-x\partial_z+z\partial_x )+\lambda \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}(x\partial_x+y\partial_y+z\partial_z) = (-x\partial_z+z\partial_x) + \lambda \cos(\varphi)r\partial_r.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary.

If we fix the value $\lambda=\sqrt{2}$ and we evaluate the vectorfields in the point (x,y,z)=(1,1,1) we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
& V_1(1,1,1)=(-1,1,0) \\
& V_2(1,1,1)=(0,-1,1)+(1,1,1)=(1,0,2)\\
& V_3(1,1,1)=(1,0,-1)+(1,1,1) = (2,1,0).
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
So clearly $\dim \langle V_1(1,1,1) , V_2(1,1,1) , V_3(1,1,1)\rangle=3$.